# ASP.NET MVC Method not found: 'System.Version System.Web.HttpRuntime.get_IISVersion()'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an MVC site using Entity Framework 5.0 running on an IIS 7.5 web server.  The site works well on my local machine, but when I upload it to the webserver I get the error:

```
Method not found: 'System.Version System.Web.HttpRuntime.get_IISVersion()'.
```

The site is running on its own integrated pipeline and I have other MVC sites running on the server without a problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the .Net Version in the IIS is different from the application version! How's the Pool configuration? Wich version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.5, which I've installed .on the server, but it's not showing up as the list of the frameworks - only v2 and v4 are showing up, so that could be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed with a reinstall of the asp.net 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

You must register the **.NET Framework** version after the installation.

1) Open a cmd window as Admin and go to the Framework v4.5 installation dir in your server and execute **aspnet_regiis.exe -r**

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\{Framework}\v4.5 /*The default folder is something like this*/
```

2) Go to the **IIS** and then change the .NET version from the current Pool where the Application is hosted.

Comment: There is no v4.5 framework folder, and the application pool for 4.5 is the same as v4.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2012/10/12/where-is-asp-net-4-5-wait-where-is-net-4-5.aspx